# Remove specific properties from all objects in parent/child-relationship of arbitrary depth

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, lodash

I have a JavaScript object that represents a parent-child relationship of arbitrary depth. How can I remove certain properties for ALL objects?

```
var persons = [{
    name: 'hans',
    age: 25,
    idontwantthis: {
      somevalue: '123'
    },
    children: [{
        name: 'hans sohn',
        age: 8,
        idontwantthiseither: {
            somevalue: '456'
        },
        children: [{
            name: 'hans enkel',
            age: 2,
            children: []
        }]
    }]
}];
```

I only want the properties **name**, **age** and **children** and get rid of all the others. The new Array should look like this:

```
var persons = [{
    name: 'hans',
    age: 25,
    children: [{
        name: 'hans sohn',
        age: 8,
        children: [{
            name: 'hans enkel',
            age: 2,
            children: []
        }]
    }]
}];
```

Comment: use recursion....

Comment: you could have use `_.pick method` but it won't help you now

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57976/deep-pick-using-lodash-underscore

Comment: @CodingKobold did you see my solution? It does what you're asking. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) and use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method for iteration, [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method for getting property name array,[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) for deleting certain property of an object , [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) for checking it's an object and [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) for checking array or not.

```
// hash map for storing properties which are needed to keep
// or use an array and use `indexOf` or `includes` method
// to check but better one would be an object    
var keep = {
  name: true,
  age: true,
  children: true
}


function update(obj, kp) {
  // check its an array
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    // if array iterate over the elment
    obj.forEach(function(v) {
      // do recursion
      update(v, kp);
    })
  // check element is an object
  } else if (typeof obj == 'object') {
    // iterate over the object keys
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
      // check key is in the keep list or not
      if (!kp[k])
        // if not then delete it
        delete obj[k];
      else
        // otherwise do recursion
        update(obj[k], kp);
    })
  }
}

update(persons, keep);
```

```js
var persons = [{
  name: 'hans',
  age: 25,
  idontwantthis: {
    somevalue: '123'
  },
  children: [{
    name: 'hans sohn',
    age: 8,
    idontwantthiseither: {
      somevalue: '456'
    },
    children: [{
      name: 'hans enkel',
      age: 2,
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}];

var keep = {
  name: true,
  age: true,
  children: true
}


function update(obj, kp) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(function(v) {
      update(v, kp);
    })
  } else if (typeof obj == 'object') {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
      if (!kp[k])
        delete obj[k];
      else
        update(obj[k], kp);
    })
  }
}

update(persons, keep);

console.log(persons);
```

Comment: yeah it will work in any type of array or depth . :)

Comment: @Mahi :  yes it is ;)

Comment: i think library doesn't approach recursion way that's why they don't have one

Answer (score 3):

just use **_.pick** and recursion

```
_.map(persons, function pickPerson(person) {
    return _.chain(person)
        .pick(['name', 'age']) // pick needed props
        .merge({
            children: _.map(person.children, pickPerson) // go to depth
        })
        .value();
});
```

Comment: solution is good . but it won't work if nested array is not in `children` key

Comment: @Mahi question condition: "I only want the properties name, age and children and get rid of all the others. " i dont care about other properties

Comment: but if nested object would be inside in ` name` key  rather than `children` key then their is problem .

Comment: @Mahi there are no infornation about it in question. If the author wants he can do verification

Comment: and OP said `arbitrary depth` but this wouldn't go after 3 depth

Comment: @Mahi what?! look at fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stasovlas/qoj90mgn/ it works perfect

Comment: yeah because you have edited . but it won't work if nested object will not be inside `children` key

Comment: @Mahi it works same before edit, i just add elegance. why nested object will not be inside children key? author say nothing about it

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursion, basically you would create a function that iterates through your object's properties and calls itself recursively if it either finds an array or a property in the whitelist of properties that you provide to it.

A function like this would do the trick:

```
/**
 * Recursively modifies the provided object in place to delete the properties that don't appear in the `properties` whitelist.
 *
 * @method isolateProperties
 * @param {Object} object - Object to modify.
 * @param {Array|String} properties - An array of strings (or a single string) containing the names of the properties to whitelist.
 */
function isolateProperties(object, properties) { /* ES 5 */
    /* if properties is not an array transform it into an array */
    if (!(properties instanceof Array)) {
        properties = [properties];
    }

    /* if the object is an array, recurse over its elements */
    if (object instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0, n = object.length; i < n; ++i) {
            /* recurse */
            isolateProperties(object[i], properties);
        }
    } else {
        /* recurse through the object's properties and recurse the ones that are in the properties array; delete the rest */
        for (var key in object) {
            /* avoid potential for hackery */
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (properties.indexOf(key) > -1) { /* properties contains the key */
                    /* recurse */
                    isolateProperties(object[key], properties);
                } else {
                    /* delete the property */
                    delete object[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and you would use it like so:

```
var persons = [{
    name: 'hans',
    age: 25,
    idontwantthis: {
        somevalue: '123'
    },
    children: [{
        name: 'hans sohn',
        age: 8,
        idontwantthiseither: {
            somevalue: '456'
        },
        children: [{
            name: 'hans enkel',
            age: 2,
            children: []
        }]
    }]
}];

isolateProperties(persons, ['name', 'age', 'children']);
```

**If you are working with modern browsers here's the ES2015 Version:**

```
/**
 * Recursively modifies the provided object in place to delete the properties that don't appear in the `properties` whitelist.
 *
 * @method isolateProperties
 * @param {Object} object - Object to modify.
 * @param {Array|String} properties - An array of strings (or a single string) containing the names of the properties to whitelist.
 */
function isolateProperties(object, properties) { /* ES 6 */
    /* if properties is not an array transform it into an array */
    if (!Array.isArray(properties)) {
        properties = [properties];
    }

    /* if the object is an array, recurse over its elements */
    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        object.forEach(element => isolateProperties(element, properties));
    } else {
        /* get the object's keys */
        const keys = Object.keys(object);
        /* recurse through the keys and recurse the ones that are in the properties array; delete the rest */
        keys.forEach(key => {
            if (properties.includes(key)) {
                /* recurse */
                isolateProperties(object[key], properties);
            } else {
                /* delete the property */
                delete object[key];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic lodash solution that receives an array of props (like `_.pick()`), transforms the array, picks the properties for each object, and if one of the properties is an array, runs `pickDeep` recursively on the array:

```js
function pickDeep(arr, propsToKeep) {
  return _.map(arr, function(obj) {
    return _(obj).pick(propsToKeep).mapValues(function(value) {
      return _.isArray(value) ? pickDeep(value, propsToKeep) : value;
    });
  });
}

var persons = [{
  name: 'hans',
  age: 25,
  idontwantthis: {
    somevalue: '123'
  },
  children: [{
    name: 'hans sohn',
    age: 8,
    idontwantthiseither: {
      somevalue: '456'
    },
    children: [{
      name: 'hans enkel',
      age: 2,
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}];

var result = pickDeep(persons, ['name', 'age', 'children']);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

And an ES6 version that uses `Object.entries()`, and `Array.prototype.reduce()` to iterate the objects properties, pick the required ones, and run `pickDeep` on arrays it finds:

```js
const pickDeep = (arr, propsToKeep) => {
  const propsToKeepDict = new Set(propsToKeep);

  const inner = (arr) =>
    arr.map((obj) =>
      Object.entries(obj).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
        propsToKeepDict.has(key) && (result[key] = Array.isArray(value) ? inner(value) : value);

        return result;
      }, {}));

  return inner(arr);
}

const persons = [{
  name: 'hans',
  age: 25,
  idontwantthis: {
    somevalue: '123'
  },
  children: [{
    name: 'hans sohn',
    age: 8,
    idontwantthiseither: {
      somevalue: '456'
    },
    children: [{
      name: 'hans enkel',
      age: 2,
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}];

const result = pickDeep(persons, ['name', 'age', 'children']);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution. **No library required**. Just Plain Javascript. Hope it helps!

```js
var persons = [{
    name: 'hans',
    age: 25,
    idontwantthis: {
      somevalue: '123'
    },
    children: [{
        name: 'hans sohn',
        age: 8,
        idontwantthiseither: {
            somevalue: '456'
        },
        children: [{
            name: 'hans enkel',
            age: 2,
            children: []
        }]
    }]
}];

for(var i in persons){
  for(var j in persons[i]){
      var propertyName = j;
     if(propertyName !== "name" && propertyName !== "age" && propertyName !== "children"){
       delete persons[i][propertyName];
    } 
      if(propertyName === "children"){
          for(var k in persons[i][propertyName]){
              propertyName2 = k;
              for(var z in persons[i][propertyName][k]){
              propertyName3 = z; 
               if(propertyName3 === "idontwantthiseither"){
                delete persons[i][propertyName][k][propertyName3]
               }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
console.log(persons);
```

Comment: idontwantthiseither is still there

Comment: @Mahi I thought the solution should get rid of a properties that is not name, age, and children. In simple words delete "idontwantthis". That's what my solution does. I'm deleteing "idontwantthis"

Comment: but idontwantthiseither is there

Comment: Sorry mate I got confused and didnt see that there was an idontwantthiseither property. Thanks for pointing that out to me :)

Comment: @Mahi  I just updated my solution. It works perfectly fine now